# Solving definite integral $\int_R^r \sqrt{R^2-t^2}dt$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Trying to find square of a circular cap, I was able to derive the next integral in polar coordinates $R\int_0^{arcsin{\frac{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}{R}}} cos{\phi}d\phi$, where $R,r=const$, and its solution is $\frac{R\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}{r}$. Then I decided to get the same solution in Cartesian coordinates and came up with the next integral $\int_0^{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}} (\sqrt{R^2-x^2}-r)dx$, where $R,r=const$. Trying to solve it I made a substitution $t=\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$ and stopped at the step, where I dont know what to do next. I have the integral which looks like $\int_R^r \sqrt{R^2-t^2}dt$ and I dont know how to solve it. Should I make one more substitution or is there another way?

Comment: substitute t = sin(u)R.

Comment: @user258250 yes, now it looks very good. How did you figure out what subst to make? or is it some standard subst?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t=\sin uR$ then the expression becomes integral from $\pi/2$ to $\arcsin(r/R)$ of $R^2\cos^2u\,du$. And then you can solve.

Comment: Please look at [mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) this will make your solutions look cleaner and more accessible.

Comment: thx, that is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Let $$\displaystyle I = \int_{R}^{r} \sqrt{R^2-t^2}\cdot 1dt\;,$$ Now Using Integration by parts, We get

So $$\displaystyle I = \left[\sqrt{R^2-t^2}\cdot t\right]_{R}^{r} - \int_{R}^{r} \frac{-2t}{2\sqrt{R^2-t^2}}\cdot t dt =\left[\sqrt{R^2-t^2}\cdot t\right]_{R}^{r} -\int_{R}^{r} \frac{\left[(R^2-t^2)-R^2\right]}{\sqrt{R^2-t^2}}dt$$

so we get $$\displaystyle I =\left[\sqrt{R^2-t^2}\cdot t\right]_{R}^{r} -\int_{R}^{r} \sqrt{R^2-t^2}dt+R^2\int_{R}^{r}\frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2-t^2}}dt$$

So We get $$\displaystyle I = \frac{\left[\sqrt{R^2-t^2}\cdot t\right]_{R}^{r} }{2}+R^2\cdot \left[\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{R}\right)\right]_{R}^{r}$$

So we get $\displaystyle I = \frac{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}\cdot r}{2}+R^2\cdot \left[\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{r}{R}\right)-\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$